# Error with types in repeated k fold with cross validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, cross-validation

I am trying to use repetitive k-fold with cross validation for a dataset, but I receive an error that has to do with types.

I tried removing the whitespace from the data values, but the error still remains

```
recipes = pd.read_csv('epi_r.csv')

keep_col = ['rating','calories','protein','fat','sodium']
recipes = recipes[keep_col]
recipes = recipes.dropna()

 bins = (-1, 3.5, 5)
group_names = ['bad','good']
recipes['rating'] = pd.cut(recipes['rating'].dropna(), bins = bins,     labels = group_names)
recipes['rating'].unique()

label_rating = LabelEncoder()

recipes['rating'] =     label_rating.fit_transform(recipes['rating'].astype(str))

rkf = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=2, n_repeats=2, random_state=50)
 for train, test in rkf.split(recipes.astype(str)):
print("%s %s" % (train, test))
xtrain, xtest = x[train], x[test]
ytrain, ytest = y[train], y[test]
```

The train and the test print, but I receive an error afterwards

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent  call last)
<ipython-input-19-102e0c6c5a53> in <module>
2 for train, test in rkf.split(recipes.astype(str)):
3     print("%s %s" % (train, test))
----> 4 xtrain, xtest = x[train], x[test]
5 ytrain, ytest = y[train], y[test]
6 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in  __getitem__(self, key)
2932                 key = list(key)
2933             indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1,
-> 2934                                                       raise_missing=True)
2935 
2936         # take() does not accept boolean indexers

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in  _convert_to_indexer(self, obj, axis, is_setter, raise_missing)
1352                 kwargs = {'raise_missing': True if is_setter  else
1353                           raise_missing}
-> 1354                 return self._get_listlike_indexer(obj, axis,   **kwargs)[1]
1355         else:
1356             try:

 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis, raise_missing)
  1159         self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer,
 1160                                     o._get_axis_number(axis),
-> 1161                                       raise_missing=raise_missing)
 1162         return keyarr, indexer
 1163 

 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in     _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)
 1244                 raise KeyError(
 1245                     u"None of [{key}] are in the   [{axis}]".format(
 -> 1246                         key=key,  axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
1247 
1248             # We (temporarily) allow for some missing keys with   .loc, except in

 KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([    0,     2,     4,     7,    10,      11,    12,    13,    14,\n               15,\n            ...\n               15844, 15846, 15847, 15850, 15853, 15854, 15857, 15859, 15860,\n              15861],\n           dtype='int64', length=7932)] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: What does the index of your dataframe look like?

Comment: use x.iloc[train]